# React Native Android device throws error for Fetch while uploading a json file : TypeError: Network request failed

Tags: android, react-native, fetch

I have written code to call Fetch method to  Post Json file to IPFS .
I am writing the  JSON file locally  which succeds , but later when i call the POST method  using FORMDATA to write json file to IPFS it fails.
Same code works fine on iOS . Not sure what is the issue with Android.

Also tried using IP of the server , using  xmlhttprequest , different options for setting cors/no-cors etc but still  getting the same error .

I am using Android version 8.0, Reactnative version 0.57 and  "react-native-fs": "^2.13.3".
Can somebody suggest an alternate way to make network calls.Cant use native code as this code is in JS library.Kindly provide your valuable feedback.
Below is the code snippet :

```
justcall(valueToWrite){
  var path = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/writeddo.json';
   //var path =  RNFS.LibraryDirectoryPath + '/writeddo.json';
    console.log("path",path);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     // write the file
     RNFS.writeFile(path, valueToWrite,'utf8')
       .then((success) => {
         console.log('FILE WRITTEN!');
         let formdata = new FormData();
         formdata.append('file', {
           uri: path,
           name: 'writeddo.json',
           type: 'multipart/form-data'
         });
         console.log("formdata",formdata);
         console.log("IPFSADD Url",IPFSADD);

           fetch(IPFSADD, {
             method: 'POST',
             headers: {
              // 'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
             },
             //mode: "no-cors",  //, cors, *same-origin
             body: formdata
            })
            // .then((serviceResponse) => { return serviceResponse.json() } ) 
             .then((serviceResponse) => {
             console.log("Justcall response", serviceResponse);
                return this.deleteJsonFile(path).then(() => {
                    resolve(serviceResponse)
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                  console.error("Error while deleting the file error:", error)
                  reject(new Error(error))
                })
            })
           .catch((error) => {
            console.error("fetch error:", error)
            reject(new Error(error))
            })

        }) // Write File
       .catch((err) => {
         console.log("Error while writing file locally" +err.toString());
         reject(new Error(err))
       });
     }) //Promise
}



fetch error: TypeError: Network request failed
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror (whatwg-fetch.js:504)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (event-target.js:172)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (XMLHttpRequest.js:580)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (XMLHttpRequest.js:394)
    at XMLHttpRequest.js:507
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (EventEmitter.js:190)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (MessageQueue.js:349)
    at MessageQueue.js:106
    at MessageQueue.__guard (MessageQueue.js:297)
    at MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (MessageQueue.js:105)
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by using RNFetchBlob to POST the file with  below code :

```
uploadToIPFS(valueToWrite , filename ,name) {
  var path = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/'+filename;
  console.log("path",path);
  let newValueToWrite =  Buffer.from(valueToWrite).toString('base64'); 
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // write the file to IPFS
        RNFetchBlob.fetch('POST',IPFSADD, {
           'Content-Type' :  'application/json', //'multipart/form-data',
         }, [
          { name : 'name', filename : filename, data: newValueToWrite},
        ])
        .then(fetchBlobResponse => {
                  console.log("[IPFS backup] UPLOAD response!", fetchBlobResponse);
                  // Ensure we have `data` and a 200 response
                  if (
                    fetchBlobResponse.data &&
                    fetchBlobResponse.respInfo &&
                    fetchBlobResponse.respInfo.status === 200
                  ) {
                    console.log("[IPFS backup] UPLOAD SUCCESS!");
                    const responseData = JSON.parse(fetchBlobResponse.data);
                    console.log(
                      "[IPFS Response " +
                      responseData
                    );
                    resolve(fetchBlobResponse.data)
                  } else {
                    reject (new Error("[IPFS backup] Upload failure! HTTP status: " +
                        fetchBlobResponse.respInfo.status));
                  }
                });
    }) //Promise
}
```